# Having trouble resuming thread when WiFi is available in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following block of code which checks to see if WiFi is available in Swift:

```
func start() {

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                if self.viewModel?.dataIsReady == true {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(StoryboardID.SegueShowFeedVC.rawValue,
                                                    sender: self)
                }else{
                    if let viewModel = self.viewModel{
                        self.onboardThree.startButton.alpha = 0.2
                        self.onboardThree.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                        viewModel.waitingForData = true
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Internet connection FAILED")
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }

    }
```

I am able to successfully check for WiFi, and correctly display the Alert to the user when WiFi is off.  However, what I'm having trouble with is that when I turn on WiFi while the app is running, and then try to continue to run the block of code, it appears to get hung (i.e. I see the activity indicator running perpetually), and the code doesn't seem to progress from this point.  Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this function get called? Do you have some kind of timer that runs every x amount of seconds for example that then calls this function or a callback somewhere in your code that calls this function?

Without seeing some more of what you have currently set up it looks to me (Going purely off the code I've got available) that you only have two scenarios covered:

1. *Start* function is called and there is no internet connection - Show an alert
2. *Start* function is called and and there is a network connection but the data is not yet ready - Display a spinner

Is the *Start* function getting called again when your data is "ready" ?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  The "Start" function is called by a button.  So after restoring connectivity, I press the button again which calls the "Start" function once again.  I figured if WiFi is restored, then the function would be called, and continue through.

Comment: Ok no problem, makes perfect sense. Where are you setting the dataIsReady property of your viewModel to be true out of curiosity?

Comment: The "Start" function is in a ViewController, and the dataIsReady is a property inside the corresponding viewModel class.

Comment: Sorry, my response wasn't clear enough. Your perform segue is only called when your dataIsReady property is true. Since your activity indicator is showing (As you said originally) looks like dataIsReady is just never getting set to true which means that code will never execute thus causing the activity indicator to always show.

Comment: The viewModel is instantiated from the AppDelegate's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method.  This explains why, if initially there was no WiFi, this value in the viewModel would be set to "false".  However, now that WiFi is restored (but with the app still running), how would I logically call to instantiate the viewModel again?

Comment: Ok no problem. Do you have anything set up that would set your dataIsReady property to false at the moment? I.e. Are you making any server calls or anything like that? If you're happy to do so, feel free to send me the entire class you're performing this code in, along with your viewModel property and I'd be happy to take a look at what you've got and make suggestions on where to go from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121920/discussion-between-nick-jones-and-syedfa).